# How do i use nested routes without having components within parent route components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Does using `react-router-dom`'s nested routes force you to render nested route components **within** parent route components? I'm new to routes and I am trying to understand.

I have a React app simulated below, and I brought in `react-router-dom` v6 a bit late in the development process. `ComponentView` renders the needed component based on title prop. I have the routes set up like below where `"/a"` & `"/b"` are mapped to a `ComponentView` component rendered according to the title value. What I want is to make `"/b"` a nested route of `"/a"` without changing the component structure. Is that possible?

I tried restructuring the routes like this:

```
<Route path="a" element={<ComponentView title="a" />}>
  <Route path="b" element={<ComponentView title="b" />} />
</Route>
```

...but if I then navigate to `"/a/b"`, I get the equivalent of `"/a"`.

From what I know of react router so far, if I want to make `"/b"` a sub of `"/a"`, that means the component rendered in `"/b"` would be rendered *in addition to* whatever component(s) is rendered by `"/a"`. Is there a way to nest the routes, but not nest the content?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { Home } from "./components/Home"
import { ComponentView } from "./components/ComponentView";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="a" element={<ComponentView title="a" />} />
        <Route path="b" element={<ComponentView title="b" />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

ComponentView.js

```
import { ComponentA } from "./ComponentA";
import { ComponentB } from "./ComponentB";

export function ComponentView(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.title === "a" ? (
        <ComponentA title={props.title} />
        ) : (
        <ComponentB title={props.title} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ComponentA.js

```
export function ComponentA(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <div style={{ height: "5rem", width: "100%" }}>
        Component A - title: {props.title}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ComponentB.js

```
export function ComponentB(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <div style={{ height: "5rem", width: "100%" }}>
        Component B - title: {props.title}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentView` doesn't render an `Outlet` for nested routes to render out their `element` content, so

```
<Route path="a" element={<ComponentView title="a" />} >
  <Route path="b" element={<ComponentView title="b" />} />
</Route>
```

renders only `<ComponentView title="a" />`, the nested route isn't reachable/renderable.

If I am understanding correctly that you want `ComponentA` to be rendered only when the path is `"/a"`, and for `ComponentB` to be rendered on path `"/a/b"`, then refactor the routes to render `<ComponentView title="a" />` as the index route of `"/a"` and `<ComponentView title="b"/>` as the nested `"b"` route of `"/a"`. This way each will be rendered independent of the other.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="a">
          <Route index element={<ComponentView title="a" />} />
          <Route path="b" element={<ComponentView title="b" />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```